# Wrong date, time and time zone in Docker image. Unable set it

Tags: python, docker

Following is my dockerFile.

```
FROM python:3.8

LABEL version="0.1"
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN  pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["sh", "-c", "python3 run_scheduler.py "]
```

I did manage to change the time_zone but the date and time was still wrong. It is showing date time as 020-06-11 12:10:37.595709, tz:Etc/UT. I needed tz as America\New_York.

Comment: Try restarting the container.

Comment: I tired to change time within container using dpkg-reconfigure tzdata. Following is output.   Which is still not correct (Actual date is 12th Jun and time is around 7:30 am)
 Current default time zone: 'America/New_York'
Local time is now:      Thu Jun 11 08:53:27 EDT 2020.
Universal Time is now:  Thu Jun 11 12:53:27 UTC 2020.

Comment: any update. was it resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the respective timezone by creating a link of `/etc/timezone` and `/etc/localtime` to point to necessary timezone file file.
In your case, point the link to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York`.

You can create the link as a part of **Docker build** or you can even **mount** it while running the container.

#### Setup TZ during build:

```
FROM python:3.8
LABEL version="0.1"
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN  ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/timezone && \
     ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime && \
     pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["sh", "-c", "python3 run_scheduler.py "]
```

#### Mount timezone while running container:

```
docker run --rm -it -v /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York:/etc/timezone:ro -v /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York:/etc/localtime:ro <image_name>
```

Comment: I am building image  on Windows 10 pro.  Its is unable to create hard link as file does not exist.

Comment: but python is created from linux as base image right? or r u using python:windowsservercore-1809?

Comment: yes, python  is created from linux base image. As soon as I try build. I get an error Its is unable to create hard link as file does not exist.  I am trying to build with  updated docker file as mentioned.

Comment: can you try `ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/timezone` and `ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime` I've updated the answer. hardlink points to **/usr/share/zoneinfo/posixrules** which doesn't work as expected.